# Resizing an image using CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I'm designing a web page which has links to several sites. 
I'm using the `a href` tag with the image of the logo of the website.
When I tried to re-size the images in the CSS file, nothing worked.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong (e.g using the wrong tag in CSS etc.)?

HTML Code:

```
 <div id="main">
    <div class="container page">
        <h1>Useful Links</h1>
        <a href="https://pcpartpicker.com/" target="_blank"><img class="links" src="/pictures/external%20links/images%20(1).jpg" alt= "PC Part Picker"></a>
        <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc" target="_blank"><img class="links" src="/pictures/external%20links/reddit.png" alt="Reddit Build a PC"></a>
        <a href="http://www.tomshardware.com/" target="_blank"><img class="links" src="/pictures/external%20links/tomshardwre.png" alt="Tom's Hardware"></a>
        <a href="http://www.cnet.com/forums/pc-hardware/" target="_blank"><img class="links" src="/pictures/external%20links/CNET-Logo.png" alt="Cnet"></a>
        <a href="http://www.pcper.com/" target="_blank"><img class="links" src="/pictures/external%20links/pcper.jpg" alt="PC Perspective"></a>
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.container a img{
    width: 200;
    height: 200;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.container{
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I think you forget the px in your css code, try to add it and check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specific the unit of measurement for your images width/height ie, px, %, etc.

If you were adding the value to the image tag itself then that 200 would automatically translate in the browser as 200px but not in the css.

So this would work as 200px by 200px

```
<a href="https://pcpartpicker.com/" target="_blank"><img class="links" src="/pictures/external%20links/images%20(1).jpg" alt= "PC Part Picker" width="200" height="200"></a>
```

but in css it has to be:

```
.container a img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Now if you want them to display in one row, remove the "display:block" property.

And they wont all fit on the same row so try reducing it to around 188px (or 19% - margin will fill the remaining space) if that is what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Add `px` to the measures of img at first.

Answer (score 0):

In your html, you can just specify a custom height and width

For example,

```
    <img class="links" src="/pictures/external%20links/images%20(1).jpg" height="200" width="200" alt= "PC Part Picker"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS code:

```
.container a img{
    width: 200;
    height: 200;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.container{
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```